# Create the [openssl-command] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-creation-request

I'd like to create a [openssl-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl-command) tag to differentiate [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) programming questions from OpenSSL command questions. As it stands, they all get lumped into [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl).

The distinction is important for Stack Overflow. Programming questions with the [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl) are almost always on-topic at Stack Overflow. [openssl-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl-command) are sometimes off-topic, and the additional tag will help classify and perhaps migrate an off-topic question.

As an example, here are two recent questions that don't appear to be programming related, but they are asked under the OpenSSL tag, because they are OpenSSL commands: *[How can I see what attributes are signed inside a PKCS 7 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567623/how-to-see-what-attributes-are-signed-inside-pkcs7)* and *[How can I extract only the signed data from a PKCS 7 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570380/how-to-extract-only-the-signed-data-from-pkcs7)*.

Does the community have any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Not considering the merits of such a tag, I don’t think users would apply it, at least in the initial revision. That makes it near useless for “help[ing to] classify and […] migrate an off-topic question”. If the audience for [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl) questions significantly differed from [openssl-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl-command) questions, it might still be useful, but I imagine people with experience in one might also have interest in the other.

Comment: "... I don’t think users would apply it, at least in the initial revision" - the tag auto-complete should list it, which will aide in its use. For those who still don't use it, folks like me who monitor [tag:openssl] will classify it.

Comment: @jww: To play devil’s advocate, the autocomplete often doesn’t seem to help; and yes, other people will tag it, sure, but then, as I stated in my answer, it’s still not very useful if you’re trying to use it to *detect* potential off-topic questions. The only use of it then would be as a way to coördinate close votes—something that, until now, has been done through mechanisms such as chat, rather than tagging.